# How can I display the invalid value that caused a Type Mismatch during Model Binding?

Tags: spring-mvc, model-binding

We're using strongly typed model and form objects in Spring 3.1 MVC, this works well and allows us to manage our with a low overhead of code. However our users like the invalid values to remain in the field when an invalid value is displayed, particularly so users don't have to retype long amounts that were off by one typo.  This works fine for validation errors, but presents a problem for binding errors, as the value will not fit in the model.  I know I can get the invalid value from the [`FieldError`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/FieldError.html#getRejectedValue%28%29), but how can I get it back to the view (JSP)?

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the BindingResult in the JSP.  You could simply get the field errors directly.  It would look something like this:

```
<forEach items="${requestScope['org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.formBean'].getFieldErrors('fieldName')}" var="fieldError">
     <!-- do something with the FieldError -->
</forEach>
```

In this case, the form bean/model attribute/command object is called "formBean", and the field is called "fieldName".  Once you have fieldError, you can do what you want with it.